# create nested elements with classnames in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm creating an element within an element for testing purpose:

```
const item = document.createElement("div");
// item.className("item");
item.className = "item";
const content = document.getElementsByClassName("item").appendChild("div");
content.className = "content";
```

However, I get the error:

> undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName("item").appendChild("div")'

Can anyone help?

P.S. Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: Why did you use `item.className("...")` but `content.className = "..."`?

Comment: You should also have a look at what `.getElementsByClassName()` returns and how `.appendChild()` works.

Comment: that was my mistake! Thanks @HerrSerker and Andreas for pointing that out.

Comment: `appendChild` takes an element reference as a parameter, not a string containing a tag name. And `document.getElementsByClassName("item")` will only select elements that are in the DOM already at that point (in case you were expecting this to select your newly created element that you stored in `item`.)

Comment: @Andreas, yes you're right, now I get 
`undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName('item').appendChild("div")')`

how can I put a new element within another new one? 
I need both `item` and `content` for function params later on.

Comment: @misorude _"will only select elements that are in the DOM already at that point"_ - That's only halve of the truth. `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a live collection of elements. The returned list will always have all matching elements regardless of when they were added to the DOM (call it in the head, add elements in the body, check the returned list at the bottom of the body and all elements will be there).

Comment: Have a look at the documentation and the examples -> [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

Comment: You use it className correct in one spot and incorrect in another.

Comment: @Andreas I’m aware node lists are live, what I meant was they should not expect to find their newly created item (`const item = ...`) with this line, as long as that item has not been appended to the DOM yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fall of 2018 the more flexible practice is to use `classList` property of HTML element

```
element.classList.add('item');
```

If I understood your logic right, the final code will be the next:

```
const item = document.createElement('div');
item.classList.add('item');
const content = document.createElement('div');
content.classList.add('content');
item.appendChild(content);
```

Comment: The TO is obviously a beginner. Imho, you should add some explanations why the script won't work and what TO has to do instead. With just the code TO is as smart as before.

Comment: @MysterX if I had the power I would give you 100 upvotes. Once I have 15 points, you will see my appreciation! :tada: 

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy. `className` is a property

```
item.className = "item";
```

Answer (score 1):

You may like to use `classList` instead of `className` as later will remove all the other class of this element.

Secondly `document.getElementsByClassName("item").appendChild("div");` will not work as `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a nodelist. You need to get the index to add the element

```
const item = document.createElement("div");
item.classList.add("item");
const content = document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].appendChild("div");
content.className = "content";
```

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a `HTMLCollection` and not a `NodeList`